# Are child objects supposed to update automatically in Entity Framework 4 Code-First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got this Venue object:

```
public class Venue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Venue Type")]
    public int VenueTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual VenueType VenueType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VenuePart> VenueParts { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, it has a collection of `VenuePart`s. I send the `Venue` to the view, and output the collection of `VenuePart`s as a table of textboxes. This gets posted back to `Edit(VenueDetailsViewModel venueDetailsViewModel)`. Using the debugger, I can verify that my change are in the `VenuePart`s collection, so I think we're good on binding.

My controller tries to update the `Venue`. It succeeds on the properties directly on the object, such as `Name`. But, unless I loop through the collection, it does not update those objects. Is that typical behavior?

```
unitOfWork.VenueRepository.Update(venueDetailsViewModel.Venue);
// Should this loop be necessary?
foreach (var venuePart in venueDetailsViewModel.Venue.VenueParts)
{
    unitOfWork.VenuePartRepository.Update(venuePart);
}
unitOfWork.Save();
```

At the moment, I'm not even worried about handling new stuff in the list or things that vanished from the list (although that is what I am tackling next). For my first step here, I just want to get the list updated. Is it necessary to loop through the collection and update each individual object? If I don't do this, they don't save. But it seems like they ought to without my loop. Are my expectations too high or am I doing something wrong?

My `repository` and `unitOfWork` objects are patterned after [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) if you are curious what that code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `unitOfWork.VenueRepository.Update(venueDetailsViewModel.Venue);` will attach the object graph in `Unchanged` state and only change the `venue` as `Modified`. One alternative would be to move the `foreach` loop to the `VenuePartRepository.Update` method.

If you allow elements of `VenueParts` to be added or removed from the UI you will have a hard time applying the changes. If this is the case you will have to load the collection in the database and compare that with the changes coming in. Then manually change the states of `VenuePart` to `Added` or `Deleted`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll try your suggestion of moving it inside the repository.